# finding comon set in different rows in cassandra

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cassandra, cql, nosql

I have a cassandra Table having two columns.
it looks like:

```
 id                            | itemlist
-------------------------------+---------
1                              | List("a", "b", "c")
2                              | List("a", "b", "c", "d")
3                              | List("a")
4                              | List("d", "e", "f")
```

I need to find the unique item sets in the list in accross the rows. for example for id=1 and id=2 and id = 3 what is the common item set?

Is there any way I can get this using single query? Can I write a UDF that can be used for this usecase.

```
class Itemlist(Model): 
default_ttl = CA_TTL_31_DAYS
gc_grace_seconds = CA_GC_GRACE_SECONDS 
keyspace = ks id = columns.Text(primary_key=True) 
itemlistlist = columns.Set(columns.Text)
```

P.S: Considering in one row itemlist value list size is in thousands.

Comment: you should normalize your table .. avoiding list of values in  a field

Comment: Can you add your table schema to your question please?

Comment: Remember Cassandra is a distributed system and scanning every row is going to be very costly. The scan has to surface across nodes and not going to be performant. Model the data differently. For example have another table with itemlist as your partition_key and item as clustering column.